# Android - Facebook connectivity fails

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

In my Android app, I am integrating the Facebook SDK to have the shareDialog in it. The share dialog open perfectly with the pre-populated details. When I clicked SHARE on top right of sharedialog screen, I am getting the below mentioned error in logcat and in Toast. Please let me know where my config needs correction.

### Logcat

```
04-17 15:15:47.140: E/Facebook(14515): Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to     
authenticate the application because of app name mismatch.  Please check the application   
name configured by the dialog.
```

Comment: Check the Package Name in developers facebook.

Comment: Have you added the line `<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />` in your manifest file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Facebook [developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/)

**Apps --> "YourApp" --> settings -->**

Then change Package name (your application package name) and Class name (your activity class name)

for an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is occuring due to mismatch of name, may be package name or class name or even application ID.

You need to check the **AndroidMainfest.xml** and also the dashboard of **https://developers.facebook.com/apps/yourAppID/settings/**. On the xml check if this is same as on the dashboard

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="app_id" />   //the app_id must be same as on the dashboard

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Also check for the **package name**, **class name** of the dashboard is same on your android app.